# Compare mobile numbers in one data frame to mobile numbers in another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

My aim is to import two excel files, one has my phone number history the other has some work numbers.

I want to compare work numbers with the phone numbers in my phone number history and store in a new matrix with the date and associated phone call duration.

At the moment I am doing it manually as per below, can someone please help me?

Thanks everyone.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import os 
clear = lambda:os.system('cls')
clear()

xls = pd.ExcelFile("C:\ - location")
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'RawData', dtype=    {'Date':np.datetime64, 'Type':str}, header=None)
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'WorkNumbers',0)

dR = df1.as_matrix()
dWN = df2.as_matrix()

Ewen = df1[(df1['Number'] == #mobile number#)]
Alex = df1[(df1['Number'] == #mobile number#)]
Nirmal = df1[(df1['Number'] == #mobile number#)]
Chris = df1[(df1['Number'] == #mobile number#)]
ChrisM = df1[(df1['Number'] == #mobile number#)]
Austofix = df1[(df1['Number'] == #mobile number#)]
Simon = df1[(df1['Number'] == #mobile number#)]
Tony = df1[(df1['Number'] == #mobile number#)]

Trial = [Ewen, Alex, Nirmal, Chris, ChrisM, Austofix, Simon, Tony]
enter code heredf3 = pd.concat(Trial)
```

[Photo of Matrix / DataFrames Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCHAE.png)

Example of the data:

```
df1:


Date            Type            Number          Duration
03/10/18    National Mobile 8156665498  4.00
03/10/18    National Mobile 8156665499  27.00
03/10/18    National Mobile 8156665500  21.00
02/10/18    National Mobile 8156665501  47.00
02/10/18    National Mobile 45687823456 47.00
02/10/18    National Mobile 45687823457 35.00
02/10/18    National Mobile 45687823458 55.00
30/09/18    National Mobile 45687823459 1.00
30/09/18    National Mobile 45687823460 41.00
30/09/18    CallForward to VoiceMail    8156665507  1.00
30/09/18    National Mobile 8156665508  3.00
29/09/18    National Mobile 8156665509  16.00
29/09/18    National Mobile 8156665510  2.00
29/09/18    National Mobile 8156665511  3.00
29/09/18    National Mobile 8156665512  2.00
28/09/18    13nnnn  8156665513  14.00
28/09/18    National Mobile 8156665514  25.00


df2:

WNumber name
45687823456 Ewen
45687823457 alex
45687823458 nirmal
45687823459 chris
45687823460 chris m
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for `df1` and `df2`? Feel free to use made up numbers and names, it is just to give an impression of your column names and structure

Comment: It sounds a lot like you want to do a [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), but it'd be easier to explain with your structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: added left/right keys as per sample data.

Does this work? Using [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['04123', '60mins'], ['04723', '30mins'], ['04568', '10mins']], columns=['Number', 'Duration'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['Bob', '04123'], ['James', '04723'], ['Someone', '04567']], columns=['Name', 'WNumber'])

df_result = pd.merge(df2, df1, left_on=['WNumber'], right_on=['Number'])
```

It yields

```
    Name WNumber Number Duration
0    Bob   04123  04123   60mins
1  James   04723  04723   30mins
```

Duplicate column can be dropped.

Comment: Antoine unfortunately it doesn't work because I need to compare it to a larger list around 1000 rows.

Comment: Why does 1000 rows not work? Merge should be able to handle that easily - I mean, very easily. Did you try it?